# How to remove libusb from Android standalone toolchain?

Tags: android, libusb, toolchain

I'm trying to compile a tool that uses `libusb` with modified `libusb` for android.
Modified `libusb` was compiled and installed to `/usr/local/lib` as expected.
The problem is that standalone `toolchain` already contains `libusb` and it hurts linking/compilation.

```
./configure
```

Returns:

```
...
checking for usb_get_string_simple in -lusb... yes
...
```

So `libusb` if found okay.

But with standalone `toolchain`:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}-gcc
export CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}=g++
export NDK=/softdev/android-ndk-r8e
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/softdev/android-ndk-r8e
export SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
export PATH=/softdev/arm-toolchain/bin:$PATH:/softdev/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm

./configure --build=x86-unknown-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-androideabi --target=arm-linux-androideabi
```

It returns:

```
...
checking for usb_get_string_simple in -lusb... no
...
```

how to make it working with standalone `toolchain`?
`libusb-0.1` is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally i was able to fix it.

1. the tool configure.ac file was not written in account to using libusb-compat (but for only libusb-0.1).

So i solved it by adding dependency while searching libusb-0.1 (-lusb-1.0):

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([usb], [usb_get_string_simple], [have_libusb=yes], [], [-lusb-1.0])
```

2.  Another problem was to make AC_CHECK find libs not in standard system /usr/local/lib folder as modified library interface was a bit different
and it tried to gcc with system one while searching with AC_CHECK_LIB. I used CPPFLAGS to set the right libs path